# What does "Windows 10 Team" option mean when submitting a UWP app to Windows 10 Store?

Tags: winapi, uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I was submitting my [converted Win32 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) to the Windows 10 Store and noticed that there was a new checkmark/option available there, that read `"Windows 10 Team"`:

[image]

What does that mean?

Also if I check that option, the next page that comes up before submitting to the store shows `Incomplete` for the `.APPX` package and doesn't allow me to finish submission:

[image]

So it would be nice to know what is `"incomplete"` about it?

Comment: Did you try searching? It seems to be for Surface Hub.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yeah, but why would they put it as a separate version of Windows? And why does it start saying that my .appx package is incomplete when I mark it as such? That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 Team == SurfaceHub (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/business/surface-hub)

The SurfaceHub only supports true UWP apps. Packaged Win32 apps (desktop-bridge) are not supported.

If your submitted package does not contain any app that actually works on the Surface Hub the store would reject it if you check "Windows 10 Team", because there is nothing that could be offered to Surface Hub users.

Comment: Thanks, man. It would help though if they had a little "info" icon next to those to explain what you did. Now it makes sense. PS. I'm just curious though about two things (just my curiosity, nothing personal): 1. Why not just call it "Surface Hub" instead of "Windows 10 Team", and 2. Who would pay $9k to $22k for a Windows computer that doesn't run Windows (i.e. desktop) apps. What am I supposed to do with it, play Candy Crush Saga.

Comment: @c00000fd "Team" describes the OS. "Hub" is the brand name for a specific hardware device. Similarly, "Desktop" describes the OS, but "Surface Pro", "Surface Go", "Surface Book", etc. are the hardware devices. (And those devices are very good at what they are designed for: business meetings.)